# c# сравнение коллекций

Tags: c#, массивы, json

Всем привет!
Ситуация следующая, у меня json файл, который отправляю на сервер, POST запрос,
 после этого я подключаюсь к БД и отправляю туда sql запрос,
 на выходе я получаю массив элементов,
мне нужно проверить корректность маппинга , проблема в том, что в json есть поля, которые содержат в себе одинаковые значения, соответственно при сравнении двух коллекций, как можно их отличить?
Пример json (**полей с одинаковыми значениями больше**):d

```
"rec": [
    {
      "app": "2022-09-13",
      "agr": 1479314397203,
      "agrend": "2022-09-13",
    }
```

Ответ из БД:
[0] "2022-09-13"
[1] "2022-09-13"
[2] "1479314397203"

Comment: Json - это не коллекция, поля в json - тоже не коллекция. Какие коллекции вы сравнивать хотите?

Comment: при десериализации получаю массив объектов json, потом получаю массив string от бд, эти два массива хочу сравнить по значениям

Comment: ну получайте строки из БД в том же порядке, что у вас в json и сравнивайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас 2 коллекции объектов -  пишите кастомный Comparer  который сравнивает, на пример, по 2 свойствам.

Answer (score 1):

```
// var myList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rec>>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Rec
    {
        public string app { get; set; }
        public long agr { get; set; }
        public string agrend { get; set; }
    }
```

Далее вы запрашиваете из БД элементы с указанными "agr", и обходя список сравниваете поля app и agrend соответственно.